# タプルから1番のindexを複数抽出する方法

Tags: swift2

//配列にタプルを格納してあります。(String,Int)
この配列から1番のindexだけを抽出することは可能でしょうか？
let aaa = [(“あ”,1210),(“い”,1215),(“う”,1220),(“い”,1228),(“あ”,1230)]

//このような配列を作りたいです
let bbb = [1210,1215,1220,1228,1230]

お願いします

Comment: Le Pere d'OO 様　
ご親切に教えてくださりありがとうございました。
こんな便利な機能があるのですね　
また宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

配列のすべての要素に同じ操作を適用した結果を新しい配列として取得する場合、`map`が有効です。

```
let aaa = [("あ",1210),("い",1215),("う",1220),("い",1228),("あ",1230)]
let bbb = aaa.map{$0.1} //->[1210, 1215, 1220, 1228, 1230]
```

これはSwift1.0(およびそれ以前のβ版)から存在する機能です。Swift2.xに特有の問題だという場合以外は、言語に関する質問にはバージョン番号のないタグを付けた方が多くの皆さんに見ていただけますよ。